# How to force Mathematica to output an expression such as Input {2,3,4}-> Output 2*3*4=24

Tags: time-series

How to force Mathematica to output an expression such as

Input {2,3,4}-> Output 2*3*4=24

as a Times like this one:

Input Times[2,3,4] -> Output 24

Comment: do you mean you want to show the intermediate steps?  Otherwise, you can try `Times @@ lst` where `lst={2,3,4}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
lst = {2, 3, 4};

Apply[Inactive[Times]]@# == Times @@ # &@lst
```

> 2*3*4==24

Or, for purposes of display,

```
Inactive[Set][Apply[Inactive[Times]]@#, Times @@ #] & @ lst
```

> 2*3*4=24

and

```
Row[{Inactive[Times] @@ #, Times @@ #}, "="] & @ lst
```

> 2*3*4=24